# Making Bootstrap Accordion with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to make a Bootstrap accordion structure using JQuery (with data from an API). I nearly have the whole structure but am having a hard time adding an extra div for the inner content, which keeps getting placed inside of my anchor tag. I would like to make HTML that looks like the following:

```
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-   
      parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
       Collapsible Group Item #2
     </a>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
     <div class="accordion-inner">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

My `JavaScript` looks like so (in addition I have a global counter):

```
function makeAccordion(reposDatum) {
  var outerGroup = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-group");  
  var outerHeading = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-heading");
  var makeId =  "#collapse" + counter;
  var mainTitle = $("<a>").append(reposDatum.name);
  $(mainTitle).addClass("accordion-toggle").attr("data-toggle",   
   "collapse").attr("data-parent", "#accordion2").attr("href", makeId);
  var innerGroupShell = $("<div>").attr("id",  
    makeId).addClass("accordion-body").addClass("collapse").html("test");
  var innerGroupInner = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-inner");

  innerGroupShell.append(innerGroupInner);  
  mainTitle.append(innerGroupShell);
  outerHeading.append(mainTitle);
  outerGroup.append(outerHeading);

  return outerGroup;
}
```

I suspect that I need to use `.after` or `.before` instead of `.append` but using `.before` just caused the div to disappear. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Did you tried using the code in my answer?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/L18fue2y/**
Of course I've used some example data in the fiddle.

```
function makeAccordion(reposDatum){
    counter++;
    $('.accordion-group').append(''+
      '<div class="accordion-heading">'+
      '<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'+(counter-1)+'" href="#collapse'+counter+'">'+
          reposDatum.name+
      '</a>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="collapse'+counter+'" class="accordion-body collapse">'+
          '<div class="accordion-inner"></div>'+
      '</div>');
}
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to create elements in jquery, not just type out HTML

Comment: Yes, @Shamoon you were right. Now I've used append instead of return. so it's working. Check the fiddle and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Your fiddle certainly works. I also realized I was using a BS 2 accordion instead of a BS 3 one, which couldn't have been helping (I was linking to the BS 3 CDN).

Answer (score 1):

There was a slight mistake in the code. the place where the text was added. just changed the location of the

```
*.html("test")*
```

Please check the code below:

```
function makeAccordion(reposDatum) {
  var outerGroup = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-group");  
  var outerHeading = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-heading");
  var makeId =  "#collapse" + counter;
  var mainTitle = $("<a>").append(reposDatum.name);
  $(mainTitle).addClass("accordion-toggle").attr("data-toggle",   
   "collapse").attr("data-parent", "#accordion2").attr("href", makeId);
  var innerGroupShell = $("<div>").attr("id",  
    makeId).addClass("accordion-body").addClass("collapse");
  var innerGroupInner = $("<div>").addClass("accordion-inner").html("test");

  innerGroupShell.append(innerGroupInner);  
  mainTitle.append(innerGroupShell);
  outerHeading.append(mainTitle);
  outerGroup.append(outerHeading);

  return outerGroup;
}
```